# how to build multiple apk using intel xdk?

Tags: intel-xdk, crosswalk-runtime

what I mean is this:

for android 4.x buildid 2 apk using crosswalk for ARM and X86

for android lower than 4.x using cordova

Is there any easy way to do that? since crosswalk supports only 4.x and greater I need
something that will manage the version code and all of that according to google rules
http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

EDIT re explained:
what I want is to build 3 apk, 2 apk with crosswalk for android 4.0+ and 1 apk with cordova for android 3.9 and bellow

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Intel XDK(v.876) only supports building APKs for devices with Android 4.2 and higher under the "Android", and "Crosswalk for Android" Build targets. The "Cordova for Android" build target allows you to specify a compatible version of Android in the [intelxdk.config.xml](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/using-the-cordova-for-android-ios-etc-build-option).

If you are interested building Android Apps ([with HTML5/CSS/JavaScript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVqp1zcMfbE)) with developer defined compatible versions of Android(any), you can select this with [Eclipse/Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). You can set the minimum and highest version of Android that your app is compatible with within the [manifest.xml file (Controlling Your App's Availability to Devices > Platform version section)](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#how).

Answer (score 0):

well, I think XDK should support Android 4.0 and above for crosswalk-for-android, instead of Android 4.2. can you please have a double check?  at least Crosswalk-for-Android support Android 4.0 and above..

Comment: yes crosswalk support android 4.0, what I want is to build 3 apk, 2 apk with crosswalk for android 4.0+ and 1 apk with cordova for android 3.9 and bellow